# How to convert a virtual key code to the corresponding unicode character on a keyboard in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to achieve this on a mac using QT.

Eg. When typed the letter 'z' key on a normal US keyboard.
NativeVirtualKey = 6. I can debug the following information:

- com.apple.keylayout.US, Key = 90, Character = 'z'
- com.apple.keylayout.SwissGerman, Key = 89, Character = 'y'
- com.apple.inputmethod.Kotoeri.KanaTyping.Japanese, Key = 12388, Character = 'つ'
- com.apple.inputmethod.Korean.2SetKorean, Key = 12619, Character = 'ㅋ'

However, when passing in the nativevirtualkey into function convertKeycodeToText(), only US and SwissGerman keyboard returns the correct character 'z' and 'y' respectively. but in Japanese and Korean, it doesn't work.

Here's the code I've tried.

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent* p_Event)
{
    if (p_Event->type() == QEvent::ShortcutOverride)
    {
        QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(p_Event);
        const QKeySequence eventKeySeq(keyEvent->key() | keyEvent->modifiers());

        qDebug() << "==================================================event\n"
                 << "Text: " << keyEvent->text()
                 << "\t| Key: " << keyEvent->key()
                 << "\t| Modifiers: " << keyEvent->nativeModifiers()
                 << "\t| ScanCode: " << keyEvent->nativeScanCode()
                 << "\t| VirtualKey:" << QString::number(keyEvent->nativeVirtualKey(), 16)
                 << "\t| KeySeq: " << eventKeySeq.toString();

        qDebug() << "Key->VK" << g_nativeKeycode((Qt::Key)(keyEvent->key()))
                 << "VK->Text" << ConvertKeyCodeToText(keyEvent->nativeVirtualKey(), 0).second.c_str();
        //ConvertKeyCodeToText(keyEvent->nativeVirtualKey(), 0);


        g_PrintKeyboardLayout();
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
std::pair<bool,std::string> ConvertKeyCodeToText(int mac_key_code, int modifiers) {

    TISInputSourceRef currentKeyboard = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
    CFDataRef layout_data = static_cast<CFDataRef>((TISGetInputSourceProperty(currentKeyboard, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData)));
    const UCKeyboardLayout *keyboard_layout = (const UCKeyboardLayout *)CFDataGetBytePtr(layout_data);
    
    int mac_modifiers = 0;
    if (modifiers & Qt::ShiftModifier)
    mac_modifiers |= shiftKey;
    if (modifiers & Qt::MetaModifier)
    mac_modifiers |= controlKey;
    if (modifiers & Qt::AltModifier)
    mac_modifiers |= optionKey;
    if (modifiers & Qt::ControlModifier)
    mac_modifiers |= cmdKey;
    
    // Convert EventRecord modifiers to format UCKeyTranslate accepts. See docs
    // on UCKeyTranslate for more info.
    UInt32 modifier_key_state = (mac_modifiers >> 8) & 0xFF;

    UInt32 dead_key_state = 0;
    UniCharCount char_count = 0;
    UniChar character = 0;
    OSStatus status = UCKeyTranslate(
                    keyboard_layout,
                    static_cast<UInt16>(mac_key_code),
                    kUCKeyActionDown,
                    modifier_key_state,
                    LMGetKbdLast(),
                    kUCKeyTranslateNoDeadKeysBit,
                    &dead_key_state,
                    1,
                    &char_count,
                    &character);

    bool is_dead_key = false;
    if (status == noErr && char_count == 0 && dead_key_state != 0) {
    is_dead_key = true;
    status = UCKeyTranslate(
                keyboard_layout,
                static_cast<UInt16>(mac_key_code),
                kUCKeyActionDown,
                modifier_key_state,
                LMGetKbdLast(),
                kUCKeyTranslateNoDeadKeysBit,
                &dead_key_state,
                1,
                &char_count,
                &character);
    }

    if (status == noErr && char_count == 1 && !std::iscntrl(character)) {
        wchar_t value = character;
        std::wstring str = std::wstring() + value;
        return std::make_pair(is_dead_key, std::string(str.begin(), str.end()));
    }
    return std::make_pair(false, std::string());
}
```

```
quint32 g_nativeKeycode(Qt::Key key)
{
    UTF16Char ch;
    // Constants found in NSEvent.h from AppKit.framework
    switch (key)
    {
    case Qt::Key_Return:
        return kVK_Return;
    case Qt::Key_Enter:
        return kVK_ANSI_KeypadEnter;
    case Qt::Key_Tab:
        return kVK_Tab;
    case Qt::Key_Space:
        return kVK_Space;
    case Qt::Key_Backspace:
        return kVK_Delete;
    case Qt::Key_Control:
        return kVK_Command;
    case Qt::Key_Shift:
        return kVK_Shift;
    case Qt::Key_CapsLock:
        return kVK_CapsLock;
    case Qt::Key_Option:
        return kVK_Option;
    case Qt::Key_Meta:
        return kVK_Control;
    case Qt::Key_F17:
        return kVK_F17;
    case Qt::Key_VolumeUp:
        return kVK_VolumeUp;
    case Qt::Key_VolumeDown:
        return kVK_VolumeDown;
    case Qt::Key_F18:
        return kVK_F18;
    case Qt::Key_F19:
        return kVK_F19;
    case Qt::Key_F20:
        return kVK_F20;
    case Qt::Key_F5:
        return kVK_F5;
    case Qt::Key_F6:
        return kVK_F6;
    case Qt::Key_F7:
        return kVK_F7;
    case Qt::Key_F3:
        return kVK_F3;
    case Qt::Key_F8:
        return kVK_F8;
    case Qt::Key_F9:
        return kVK_F9;
    case Qt::Key_F11:
        return kVK_F11;
    case Qt::Key_F13:
        return kVK_F13;
    case Qt::Key_F16:
        return kVK_F16;
    case Qt::Key_F14:
        return kVK_F14;
    case Qt::Key_F10:
        return kVK_F10;
    case Qt::Key_F12:
        return kVK_F12;
    case Qt::Key_F15:
        return kVK_F15;
    case Qt::Key_Help:
        return kVK_Help;
    case Qt::Key_Home:
        return kVK_Home;
    case Qt::Key_PageUp:
        return kVK_PageUp;
    case Qt::Key_Delete:
        return kVK_ForwardDelete;
    case Qt::Key_F4:
        return kVK_F4;
    case Qt::Key_End:
        return kVK_End;
    case Qt::Key_F2:
        return kVK_F2;
    case Qt::Key_PageDown:
        return kVK_PageDown;
    case Qt::Key_F1:
        return kVK_F1;
    case Qt::Key_Left:
        return kVK_LeftArrow;
    case Qt::Key_Right:
        return kVK_RightArrow;
    case Qt::Key_Down:
        return kVK_DownArrow;
    case Qt::Key_Up:
        return kVK_UpArrow;
    default:
        ;
    }

    if (key == Qt::Key_Escape)  ch = 27;
    else if (key == Qt::Key_Return) ch = 13;
    else if (key == Qt::Key_Enter) ch = 3;
    else if (key == Qt::Key_Tab) ch = 9;
    else ch = key;

    CFDataRef currentLayoutData;
    TISInputSourceRef currentKeyboard = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();

    if (currentKeyboard == NULL)
        return 0;

    currentLayoutData = (CFDataRef)TISGetInputSourceProperty(currentKeyboard, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData);
    CFRelease(currentKeyboard);
    if (currentLayoutData == NULL)
        return 0;

    UCKeyboardLayout* header = (UCKeyboardLayout*)CFDataGetBytePtr(currentLayoutData);
    UCKeyboardTypeHeader* table = header->keyboardTypeList;

    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t*)header;
    // God, would a little documentation for this shit kill you...
    for (quint32 i=0; i < header->keyboardTypeCount; i++)
    {
        UCKeyStateRecordsIndex* stateRec = 0;
        if (table[i].keyStateRecordsIndexOffset != 0)
        {
            stateRec = reinterpret_cast<UCKeyStateRecordsIndex*>(data + table[i].keyStateRecordsIndexOffset);
            if (stateRec->keyStateRecordsIndexFormat != kUCKeyStateRecordsIndexFormat) stateRec = 0;
        }

        UCKeyToCharTableIndex* charTable = reinterpret_cast<UCKeyToCharTableIndex*>(data + table[i].keyToCharTableIndexOffset);
        if (charTable->keyToCharTableIndexFormat != kUCKeyToCharTableIndexFormat) continue;

        for (quint32 j=0; j < charTable->keyToCharTableCount; j++)
        {
            UCKeyOutput* keyToChar = reinterpret_cast<UCKeyOutput*>(data + charTable->keyToCharTableOffsets[j]);
            for (quint32 k=0; k < charTable->keyToCharTableSize; k++)
            {
                if (keyToChar[k] & kUCKeyOutputTestForIndexMask)
                {
                    long idx = keyToChar[k] & kUCKeyOutputGetIndexMask;
                    if (stateRec && idx < stateRec->keyStateRecordCount)
                    {
                        UCKeyStateRecord* rec = reinterpret_cast<UCKeyStateRecord*>(data + stateRec->keyStateRecordOffsets[idx]);
                        if (rec->stateZeroCharData == ch) return k;
                    }
                }
                else if (!(keyToChar[k] & kUCKeyOutputSequenceIndexMask) && keyToChar[k] < 0xFFFE)
                {
                    if (keyToChar[k] == ch) return k;
                }
            } // for k
        } // for j
    } // for i
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're casting `mac_key_code` to a UInt16. Are you sure asian characters fit in that? I'm pretty sure they can be longer than 2 bytes.

Comment: Why are you not using `QKeyEvent::text()` if you are interested in the text (unicode) representation of the key?

Comment: @JarMan because the documentation states that it takes in UInt16 virtualKeyCode.

Comment: @m7913d because I'm trying to convert nativeVirtualKey code to it's respective unicode (based on what keyboard layout/language is set)